# How to read XML atributes from Actionscript Arraycollection?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, arraycollection

I'm reading an XML file with the httpservice in actionscript, and putting it into an arraycollection like this (where readings is the repeating node and data is the root node):

```
graphData = new ArrayCollection([event.result.data.readings]);
```

However I want to change the format of the xml file im reading to put the values in as attributes instead of values between tags (the reason im doing this is the xml files where huge and this method would require just one line with 5 attributes per reading, rather than 5 open and closing tags on separate lines).

Its loading ok into the array collection, but how do I access the attributes?
Before I would access the time value say as follows:

```
graphData.getItemAt(0).time
```

so I figured it may be as easy as:

```
graphData.getItemAt(0).@time
```

but this doesnt work, can it be done?

Comment: Actually just seen the best solution may be to load data as XML list instead, is this the only way?

Comment: What do you see in graphData when you drop a debug break point on the line after: graphData = new ArrayCollection([event.result.data.readings]); you should be able to expand graphData in the variables window to see the type of object of each element in the ArrayCollection?  You can probably see from there yourself how to correct the issue, the way E4X works in Flex is a bit of a mystery but if it "sees" multiple nodes with a given name it returns them in an array collection otherwise it's an Object, without more info it's hard to say whats going wrong here.

Comment: Why not use an XMLListCollection?  Either that or translate the XML into Value Objects and put those in the ArrayCollection.  Or even better, re-work your service so it returns Value Objects via AMF and don't deal w/ XML at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

`graphData = new ArrayCollection([event.result.data.readings])`

Just creates an AC with one value in it, which will be an XMLList. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but it's probably not what you had in mind. Do something like this:

```
var graphData:XMLList = event.result.data.readings;
// Now get data for individual readings
trace("time for first reading", graphData[0].@time);
trace("time for second reading", graphData[1].@time);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, yes apologies that example I gave was for the case when there was only one item in the xml file. I tried what you suggested however it still wont work, perhaps the xml format im trying is incorrect? Its as follows:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
 <reading temp="37.506" time="1297642337200"/>`
Also, do I need to change the format of the httpservice to e4x?

Comment: You definitely want your result format to be e4x rather than object if you're going to use the XML syntax to navigate / select within your set, it unfortunately doesn't apply to objects.